# Postgresql sort using a substring

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
==========================
id            name       
--------------------------
1             telephone
2             microphone
3             media
4             phone
```

I'm using `findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String letter)` to get the data that contains the substring (**pho**). The results are:

```
==========================
    id            name       
    --------------------------
    1             telephone
    2             microphone
    4             phone
```

But I want to also sort the output using the substring in the **autosuggesting order**. Like this:

```
 ==========================
    id            name       
    --------------------------
    4             phone
    1             telephone
    2             microphone
```

Does anyone know how to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `position()` for that and order by it

```
select * from your_table
where position('pho', name) > 0
order by position('pho', name)
```